# How to filter a JSON Array, with an eventListener input value at keyup

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

I want to build a search filter, like forEach trough a array of obj's like this one:

```
const lngLatLocation = [
  {
    "id": "alster",
    "name": "Alster",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alster",
    "coordinates": [9.997649, 53.557344]
  },
  {
    "id": "elbphilharmonie",
    "name": "Elbphilharmonie",
    "link": "https://www.elbphilharmonie.de/en/elbphilharmonie",
    "coordinates": [9.984198, 53.541267]
  },
  {
    "id": "rathaus",
    "name": "Rathaus / TownHall",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburg_City_Hall",
    "coordinates": [9.992061, 53.550252]
  },
  {
    "id": "aplantenUnBloomen",
    "name": "Planten Un Blomen",
    "link": "https://www.hamburg.com/explore/outdoors/11872624/planten-un-blomen/",
    "coordinates": [9.982028, 53.560427]
  }
]
```

And filter with an input field for the name.
One each keyup.

```
      document.querySelector('.location-filter').addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        // FILTER HERE FOR INPUT VALUE
        const filteredLocations = lngLatLocation.filter(({name}) => name == input.value);
        console.log(filteredLocations);

      });
```

at my example i am just finding "Alster" when i am case sensitive and when the string is complete.

What i want is that when i type "a" into the input he should search all item from json-array where the first letter is "a" and put them into the new array.
like an reactive search filter.

Comment: When you type 'A', You want Alster to appear, because the word starts with a. But you don't want the rest of the items in the search results which are Elbphilharmonie, Rathaus / TownHall, Planten Un Blomen even though it contains a. Is that right?

Comment: @Ajay Varghese, yes that's right. Only filtered by passing the actual name. Letter after letter.

Comment: You can make use of `startsWith` string function. @Mr. has posted the usage as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

although i did not verify my solution by executing it, it feels to me that you need to tweak your filter a litte bit.

if you want case in-sensitive, i would try

```
lngLatLocation.filter(({name}) => name.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix.toLowerCase()));
```

and in you prefer case sensitive, then just remove the `.toLowerCase()`